# Dropdown enabling and disabling

Tags: angular, angular-material

**My Code:**

```html
<mat-select 
[formControl]="Rooms" [(ngModel)]="dropdown"placeholder="ChooseRooms"multiple>
<mat-option *ngFor="let room of RoomList" [value]="room">
   {{room}}
</mat option>
</mat-select>

<mat-select 
[formControl]="devices" [disabled] = "!dropdown"placeholder="ChooseDevices"multiple>
<mat-option [value]="device" disabled>
   {{device}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Problem:**

In the above code, I have two dropdowns "Rooms" and "Devices" in which options are in the form of checkboxes.

From above code, I am able to enable second dropdown "devices" whenever I checked any checkbox in the first dropdown but, I am unable to disable the second dropdown "devices" whenever I unchecked any checkbox.

Comment: Why are you mixing both reactive and template driven form. It's not recommended to use both. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739509/mixing-reactive-form-with-template-form

Comment: you should not be checking to see if the first dropdown exists. You should add a selectionChange event to the first dropdown, then check to see if all boxes are unchecked. Inside the same function, you should define a variable that will be false if any of the boxes is checked. Use this same variable to determine if the second dropdown should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to change condition for `disabled` property like -  [disabled]="!dropdown.length"

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="dropdown" placeholder="ChooseRooms" multiple>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let room of Rooms" [value]="room">
   {{room}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<mat-select  [disabled]="!dropdown.length" placeholder="ChooseDevices" multiple>
   <mat-option [value]="devices">
   {{devices}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: it is showing has cannot assign property length to undefined

Comment: you need to create a variable 'dropdown' to TS file.