# angular - select checkbox only if values in array A exist in array B

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm iterating through an array to check if some selected values exist in there then a checkbox should be checked. When I log the results, its able to produce the correct response `('hello')` in the console meaning the code works perfectly but I don't know why its not able to check the checkbox

```
this.selected = [ 1, 8032, 8042, 8047, 8021, 7986];

this.srvresp = [{id:11, name:'AA'}, {id:8032, name:'BB'}, {id:10, name:'CC'}, {id:409, name:'DD'}, {id:300, name:'EE'} ,{id:302, name:'FF'}, {id:478, name: 'GG'}, {id:8042, name: 'HH'}, {id:8047, name:'II'}, {id:8021, name:'JJ'}, {id:7986, name:'KK'}];

for (const  s of this.srvresp) {
  for (const  selected of this.selected) {
    if (s.id == selected) {
      console.log('hello')
      s.checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of srvresp; index as ind">
 <input [(ngModel)]="item.checked" formControlName="selectedStudents" [value]="item.id" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="-item-{{ind}}">

</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine when I remove the `formControlName` directive. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55739635/11755228), mixing Template-Driven Forms and Reactive Forms is not a good idea.

Comment: Add you whole component and html code,

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix Template-Driven and Reactive forms to avoid conflicting behaviour - you should replace excess `formControlName` attribute usage.