# In PrimeNG, how do I bind a p-dropdown selected value to a form control?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular13, form-control, primeng-dropdowns

I'm using Angular 13 and PrimeNG 13.  I would like to bind a dropdown to a form control.  In my edit form, I use a p-dropdown like so

```
            <p-dropdown [options]="clients" placeholder="Select a Client" optionLabel="name"
                [(ngModel)]="editClientObj"  
                dataKey="clientId" 
                formControlName="clientId"></p-dropdown>
```

My "options" value is an array of objects that look like this ...

```
[{name: 'Mike', clientId: 3}, { ... }]
```

In my service file, I trigger the function that sets up the form with the proper values

```
  edit(obj:ClientOrder){
    this.editClientObj = obj;
    ...
    this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
    ...
      clientId: [obj.clientId, Validators.required]
    });
```

However when I submit my form, the form control's "clientId" field is set to the objecct, {name: 'Mike', customerId: 3}, instead of just the ID.  How do I adjust my p-dropdown so that it only binds the ID and not th eentire object?

Comment: editClientObj which kind of object is ?

Comment: It's of type "ClientOrder".  To be honest, I would prefer not to have this.  If I set the value in the form (i.e. the formbuilder group), and then I bind to the form, I shouldn't need to set "ngModel" to an additional object, right?

Comment: you could declare editClientObj as a string and automatically achieve what you desire in editClientObj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `optionValue` input binding to select id value

```
<p-dropdown [options]="clients" placeholder="Select a Client" optionLabel="name"
                [(ngModel)]="editClientObj"  
                dataKey="clientId"  optionValue="clientId"
                formControlName="clientId"></p-dropdown>
```

**Note:** You should not mix reactive and template driven form together.

**[For More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739509/mixing-reactive-form-with-template-form)**

**[Prime Ng Official Doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/dropdown#:%7E:text=of%20an%20option.-,optionValue,Name%20of%20the%20value%20field%20of%20an%20option.,-optionDisabled)**

Comment: The answer from @Chellappan வ seems fine. You can also check the official [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/dropdown) under the chapter Value Binding.

Comment: Thanks.  Although this does properly bind the value to the form control, it introduces a new problem -- the originally selected value that I might want to edit is no longer selected.  The first (placeholder) value is always selected.

Comment: Why are you using reactive form and template driven form together can you please use one and try?

Comment: I'm not having success with either option but it's probably because I'm not too knowledgeable with PrimeNG.  I'd be happy with any solution that binds to a form control and also displays the property contained in my form builder.

Comment: Can you please check this Here it's working fine :https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-ug6c6b?file=src/app/app.component.ts.

Comment: If possible please reproduce the issue in this stackblitz

Comment: Would it be possible to have your demo have a preselected value in the drop down?

Comment: @Dave Updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-ug6c6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts please check

Comment: The demo doesn't appear to be working.  When I change to try and select the other Mike option ("Mike 2") by changing "clientId = new FormControl(3); " to "clientId = new FormControl(2); ", it is not selecting "Mike 2".

Comment: Without dataKey binding it's working fine. Any specific reason using dataKey input property?

Comment: dataKey was/is not a requirement.  I confirmed it worked on your demo.   thx!

Answer (score 1):

Html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <p-dropdown [options]="clients" [autoDisplayFirst]="false" optionLabel="name"
    formControlName="selClient" optionValue="clientId">
  </p-dropdown>
</form>
```

.ts component code:

```
export class DropdownBindingComponent implements OnInit {

  clients: Client[];
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.clients = [
      { name: 'Mike', clientId: 3 },
      { name: 'George', clientId: 4 },
      { name: 'Steph', clientId: 5 }
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      selClient: [null, Validators.nullValidator]
    })

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("data change", data['selClient']);//output 3,4 or 5
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: I see you're adding the extra field "selectedClient", but I already have this value in my "this.form = this.formbuilder.group({ ..." so it feels like I'm tracking that value in two places if I add a field "selectedClient".  Is there any way to bind the value of the control to the form group's value?

Comment: You can remove it from the code, see edit. 
Selected value is binded to 'selClient' prop of the form.