# Angular question, formControl conflicts with ngModel?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, input, ngmodel

I am dynamically populating a table with inputs as:

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let cell of cells; let i = index;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form class="number-form">
          <mat-form-field class="number-full-width" style="height: 75px !important">
            <mat-label>Number {{cell.value}}</mat-label>
              <input matInput matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="cell.value" [formControl]="_number_form_control"/>
            <mat-error *ngIf="_number_form_control.hasError('number') && !_number_form_control.hasError('required')">
              Please enter a valid number
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="_number_form_control.hasError('required')">
              A number is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

In the TS side:

```
export class CELLCLS {
  value: number = 1.0;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-work',
  templateUrl: './my-work.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-work.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyWorkComponent {
  public cells: CELLCLS[] = [];
  public _number_form_control = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/)]);
  public _matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  
  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Initially, when I first populated the cells, then the previous set value in cell.value will be reset to 1.0, and got the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, then I added detectChanges, this error is gone, and I was able to avoid the error, but cell.value still gets reset to 1 when I pushed in a new cell. After I remove [formControl], then I am seeing the value gets updated and preserved. So I guess ngModel is conflicting with formControl in this case. What should I do if I want to keep formControl?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739509/mixing-reactive-form-with-template-form